# Trying to use randint to generate a unique value and assign it to an item in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, encryption

this code is supposed to take each unique letter from a string then generate a unique random number to become its value, then append it together. I have the unique letter part, but can't generate a unique random number. I don't know how to search my dictionary to find if the value is unique. Also apologies for sloppy code, I'm new to coding.

```
    '''This function takes plaintext and then encrypts it'''
reference = {}
plainText = input("Enter your text for encryption here:\n")
counter = 0
while counter < len(plainText):
    try:
        for i in plainText[counter]:
            check = False
            for item in reference.values():
                if item == i:
                    check = True   
            while check == False:
                    value = randint(10,19)
                    if value not in reference:
                        check = True
                        reference.update({i:value})
            counter +=1
    except IndexError:
        print('Error. Please try again\n')
    encryptedText = ""
for j in plainText:
    encryptedText = encryptedText + str(reference[j])
print("Here is your encypted text!\n"+encryptedText)
```

Comment: What is your expexcted output from a certain input? An example would help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do. I should suggest using a set to get the unique items:

```
text = set(input())
reference = {i: random.randint(10, 99) for i in set}

encrypted = text
for char, valin reference.items():
    encrypted = encrypted.replace(char, str(val))

print(encrypted)
```

The set hold each unique item in the string. The dict comprehension on line 2 takes each item in the set, and pairs it with a random value (I chose 10-99 as they are all 2-digit to help decrypt if necessary). The for loop replaces the text input in the following way: it takes each character in the reference dict and replaces it with the corresponding random value.
Just for reference, the `random` module is not recommended for actual encryption as it is `pseudo-random` and can be cracked easily. The `secrets` module is recommended for real application